# Tealium utag.link() not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tagging, universal-analytics, tealium

I am working on Tealium integration with Google analytics. My application is on ruby on rails.
I have added utag.js in my javascripts assest folder.

Following is working. I can see Google analyitcs collect call for same.

```
utag.view({'my_udo_variable' : 'udo_variable_value'});
```

But utag.link is not working.

```
utag.link({'my_udo_variable' : 'udo_variable_value'});
```

Any idea why link is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added event_category and event_action attributes then it worked for me. eg.

```
utag.link({'my_udo_variable' : 'udo_variable_value', 'event_category' : 'test', 'event_action' : 'click'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Google requires that a category and action be populated for a link to work. The label is optional.